# How do undefined components work in Vue.js - Vue.js + Pug

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pug

I was just going through some Vue.js code right [**HERE**](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/develop/website/client/components/tasks/task.vue#L19). And came across the following Vue.js + PUG code , basically its just PUG templating:

```
menu-dropdown.task-dropdown(
  v-if="!isRunningYesterdailies",
  :right="task.type === 'reward'",
  ref="taskDropdown",
  v-b-tooltip.hover.top="$t('options')"
)
```

Now when something like below is in PUG i understand that a `div` with the classes will be outputted.

```
.d-flex.justify-content-between
```

But what about when something is not preceded by a `.` ? What does it mean ?

Like what exactly is `menu-dropdown` , I was thinking its a component but when i look to the bottom of the file , i see no component named `.menu-dropdown` , IE i see only the following components loaded:

```
components: {
  approvalFooter,
  approvalHeader,
  MenuDropdown,
},
```

So where is `.menu-dropdown` coming from and what exactly is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like without the leading dot, pug renders a component

```
<menu-dropdown class="task-dropdown" ...more data here../ ></menu-dropdown>
```

Vue internally automatically creates an alias from user-name to UserName, and vice versa, so you can use whatever you like. It’s generally best to use UserName in the JavaScript, and user-name in the template.

Comment: thanks for the answer will accept , i kind of got a little hint when i was reading ::- https://flaviocopes.com/vue-components/ :)